# How to get the definite product of Sin squared?

Tags: special-functions

I want to solve this for different values of D using mathematica. But I don't know how to write the program for this calculation. Please help.
[image]

Edit: I tried to use the "Definite product" function, but I can't include the $(m-1)$ part in the product $sin^2 \theta_{(m-1)}$. Help me write the program. Thank you.

Comment: Are you wanting to use Mathematica / Wolfram Language? If you have Mathematica installed, you can start by looking at the documentation for Sum, Product, Sin, etc. Once you've done that, if you're still unable to complete your task, update your question with what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum _{n=2}^3 \text{d$\theta $}_n^2 \left(\prod _{m=2}^n \sin ^2\left(\theta _{m-1}\right)\right)$$

```
Sum[Product[Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], m - 1]]^2 , {m, 2, n}] *
    Subscript[  d\[Theta], n]^2, {n, 2, 3}]
```

$$\text{d$\theta $}_2^2 \sin ^2\left(\theta _1\right)+\text{d$\theta $}_3^2 \sin ^2\left(\theta _1\right) \sin ^2\left(\theta _2\right)$$